# Access template parameter when already in an {{#each}}

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'd like to access a parameter template while I'm on a `{{#each}}` already. Something like:

```
<template name="overview">  
  {{> userList users=users level=0}}
</template>

<template name="userList">  
  {{#each users}}
    <div class="level{{../something}}">
    <!-- not working, how can i access {{something}} here ? -->
    {{>userList users=users level=subLevel}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>  


Template.userList.helpers({

    subLevel: function() {
        return this + 1;
    }
});
```

but it's not working, do you have any idea ?

Technically, I'm calling recursively a template, and I'd like to know at what level my template is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found that the best way to achieve that was to add a `level` key in my array of users instead of passing it with a parameter. Spacebars seems to no be able to achieve what I wanted initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but this doesn't look right. A template calling itself leads to an infinite loop. For example, create a new meteor project and try to call {{> hello}} inside "hello" template. It doesn't work.

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
  {{> hello}}
</template>
```

There must be another way to do what you're trying to do...

Comment: This seems like a totally valid use case for say a tree view of management users within a company?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template name="overview">  
  {{> userList users=users level=0}}
</template>

<template name="userList">  
  {{#each users}}
    <div class=level> 
    {{>userList users=users level=subLevel}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Because you have enclosed level variable in double quotes that will not be evaluated.